# opentsdb query Filters literal_or

Tags: opentsdb

**JSON**

```
{
"start": "2016/04/12 04:16:00",

"end": "2016/04/12 16:16:00",

"queries": [

{
   "aggregator": "avg",

   "downsample": "1h-avg",

"filters":

 [

{

"filter": "1000009727000|1000009727018|1000009727028|10000097270404",

"groupBy": false,

"tagk": "neId",

"type": "literal_or"

}

],

"metric": "150214"

}

]

}
```

meet problem

> “No such name for 'tagv' 10000097270404”

others tagv exist

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentsdb/_47BHtew1sQ :

The default is to error out but users can set "tsd.query.skip_unresolved_tagvs" to true and it will pass the query through.

And it worked with OpenTSDB 2.3 for me.